# Is it possible to force R to calculate large numbers?

Tags: r

Hi right know I am trying to calculate large numbers 3**1000000 and R print Infinite, is it possible to force R to make the calculation though it may take more time...

If not do you know any programming language that can make the calculations.

Thank you

Kylian

Comment: ** is exponential and R prints Inf. Try it and tell me if your works maybe I have hardware limitations...

Comment: @Gill Bates: ** is a synonym of ^.  Mathematica is capable of doing the calculation (your number is really big)

Comment: This sounds like an x-y problem.  Why do you need to compute 3**1000000 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `gmp`can deal with big numbers:

```
library(gmp)

x <- as.bigz(3)
y <- as.bigz(1000000)
z <- pow.bigz(x, y)
print(z)
```